# selecting rows depending on the first digit of an integer in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using SQL in PostgreSQL I need to select all the rows from my table called "crop" when the first digit of the integer numbers in column "field_id" is 7.

```
select *
from crop
where (left (field_id,1) = 7)
```

Comment: What's the problem with your attempt?

Comment: Change your where condition to ```where cast(field_id as text) like '7%'```

Comment: Is the _column_ field_id of type integer?

Comment: Integers don't have a left most digit.  They're binary values, and I'm guessing you don't want the left most *bit*?  As you want the left most digit of ***the decimal string representation of an integer***, you first need to convert the integer to a string...

Comment: Hi, yes field_id is an integer column. Thibaut, your solution works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

First, you know that the column is a number, so I would be inclined to explicitly convert it, no matter what you do:

```
where left(crop::text, 1) = '7'
where crop::text like '7%'
```

The conversion to `text` is simply to be explicit about what is happening and it makes it easier for Postgres to parse the query.

More importantly, if the value has a fixed number of digits, then I would suggest using a numeric range; something like this:

```
where crop >= 700000 and crop < 800000
```

This makes it easier for Postgres to use an index on the column.

Answer (score 0):

Try with cast, like this:

```
select *
from crop
where cast(substring(cast(field_id as varchar(5)),1,1) as int) = 7
```

where 5 in varchar(5) you should put number how long is your integer.

Comment: `cast(x as int) = 7` rather than `x = '7'`?  And why the assumption of 5 digits, rather than just using postgresql's `text` type?